# How to find contains into Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

With that query I can find all name that **equal** to `Jhone`

`{ "query": { "match": { "name": { "query": "Jhone", "type" :"phrase" }}}}`

But how can I find all the name that **start with** `Jhone` ?

I have tried to put `Jhone*` like :

`{ "query": { "match": { "name": { "query": "Jhone*", "type" :"phrase" }}}}`

But that not work

Comment: What is the field type for name?

Answer (score 0):

Match query is used to find all those documents that have the exact search term (ignore the case), assuming that you are using the `name` field of `text` type.

You can use [prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) to find all the name that starts with `Jhone`

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "name":"smith Jhone"
}
{
    "name":"Jhone smith"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix" : { "name" : "Jhone" }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67805874",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Jhone smith"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

You can even use a [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "name": "Jhone*"
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67805874",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Jhone smith"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @MicrosoctCprog did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)

Answer (score 0):

On the top of what ESCoder Mentioned

- If you want to speed up `Prefix Queries` .. SEE [THIS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-prefixes.html)

[image]